# Not getting Jquery response

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have return small function. I can see the response in console but i am not getting response when i do alert(response).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/students/results?start="+start+"&end="+end_date+"&id=<%= params[:id] %>",
       success: function (response) {
         alert(response);
       }
});
```

Please help.

Comment: What did see in the console?

Comment: when i do console.log(response), I am getting Object { results=[10], query={...}}

Comment: Check for console.log(response.results)

Comment: Did you try hitting the direct url in browser? with values for start, end and id?

Comment: Got the expected response using console.log(response.query).

Answer (score 1):

Best way to check json is open your chrome console copy paste below code and then enter

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
    ]
};
```

This will return `undefined`, Now paste below code and then enter

```
myJSONObject.bindings
```

This will return `[Object, Object, Object]`

Similarly for `myJSONObject.bindings[0].ircEvent` it will return `PRIVMSG`.

So check your response and you can write something like following

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/students/results?start="+start+"&end="+end_date+"&id=<%= params[:id] %>",
       success: function (response) {
         jQuery('#some_text_field_id').val(response.bindings[0].ircEvent)
       }
});
```

I hope this will help.